# Sending a SOAP request using Savon

Tags: web-services, soap, savon

I am having trouble with a SOAP request I would like to send using Savon.

I get the following error:

```
{:fault=>   {:faultcode=>"soap:Client",    :faultstring=>
    "Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"api\"). Expected elements are <{}Eft>,<{}Customer>,<{}Safekey>,<{}Fraud>,<{}Customfield>,<{}BankTransfer>,<{}Creditcard>,<{}Basket>,<{}TransactionType>,<{}Ebucks>,<{}Loyalty>,<{}Soulstace>,<{}TransactionRecord>,<{}AdditionalInformation>,<{}Api>,<{}Autopay>,<{}Stage>,<{}Globalpay> "}}
```

My .rb file looks like this:

```
require 'savon'
require 'pp'
require 'rubygems'

client = Savon.client({
  :wsdl => "https://staging.payu.co.za/service/PayUAPI?wsdl",
  :pretty_print_xml => true, 
  :log_level => :debug, 
  :wsse_auth => ["Staging Integration Store 2", "XSWYgMUA"],
})

request_msg = {
  :Api => "ONE_ZERO",
  :Safekey => "{826BD3C4-9663-48B0-804B-044BAA6A57F1}",
  :TransactionType => "PAYMENT",
  :AdditionalInformation => {
    :merchantReference => "mercRef_1350046243",
    :cancelUrl => "http://example.com/cancel-page/",
    :returnUrl => "http://example.com/return/",
    :supportedPaymentMethods => "CREDITCARD"
  },
  :Customer => {
    :email => "john@doe.com",
    :firstName => "John",
    :lastName => "Doe",
    :merchantUserId => 1350046243
  },
  :Basket => {
    :amountInCents => 100,
    :currencyCode => "ZAR",
    :description => "Basket description comes here"
  }
}

begin
  set_transaction = client.call(:set_transaction) do
    message(request_msg)
  end

rescue Savon::SOAPFault => error
    pp error.to_hash

end
```

And here is the working SOAP request XML (Tested in SoapUI) I would like to send using the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-9" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:Username>Staging Integration Store 1</wsse:Username>
     <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">78cXrW1W</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns1:setTransaction>
    <Api>ONE_ZERO</Api>
    <Safekey>{45D5C765-16D2-45A4-8C41-8D6F84042F8C}</Safekey>
    <TransactionType>PAYMENT</TransactionType>
    <AdditionalInformation>
    <merchantReference>mercRef_1350046243</merchantReference>
     <cancelUrl>http://example.com/cancel-page/</cancelUrl>    
     <returnUrl>http://example.com/return/</returnUrl>
     <supportedPaymentMethods>CREDITCARD</supportedPaymentMethods>
    </AdditionalInformation>
    <Customer>
     <email>john@doe.com</email>
     <firstName>John</firstName>
     <lastName>Doe</lastName>
     <merchantUserId>1350046243</merchantUserId>
    </Customer>
    <Basket>
     <amountInCents>100</amountInCents>
     <currencyCode>ZAR</currencyCode>
     <description>Basket description comes here</description>
    </Basket>
   </ns1:setTransaction>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```